# How to convert a single column array that has nothing to a single column dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Here is my code

```
df_y_Codes = pd.DataFrame(y_pred_prob_Codes)
```

y_pred_prob_Codes is an array that has one row and one column of empty data

```
y_pred_prob_Codes
Out[226]: [()]

len(y_pred_prob_Codes)
Out[227]: 1
```

when I run my code above

I get a one row dataframe but no columns

```
df_y_Codes
Out[228]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [0]

df_y_Codes.shape
Out[229]: (1, 0)
```

### BUT

When I get array with a non empty value

```
y_pred_prob_Codes
Out[234]: [('BLUE',)]

len(y_pred_prob_Codes)
Out[235]: 1
```

the dataframe has that value in a column

```
df_y_Codes
Out[236]: 
     0
0  BLUE

df_y_Codes.shape
Out[237]: (1, 1)
```

How can I fix that even if the array value is empty it should make a column in that dataframe?

Comment: How was the method supposed to know you need  one column when you have no data inside ? Maybe `pd.DataFrame([(None)])` ?

Comment: ok, how to fill empty cells in array with None?

Comment: I don't know how you get the array, but `y_pred_prob_Codes.append(None)` ?